# Eclipse Mars crashes when entering SVN settings with JavaHL library added

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, eclipse-mars, javahl

I have installed Eclipse Mars on Ubuntu 14.04 and added SVN support by installing Subclipse. I followed [CollabNet instructions](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL#head-bb1dd50f9ec2f0d8c32246430c00e237d27a04fe) to enable JavaHL support. When I launch Eclipse (from the command line or from the launcher) and go to Window -> Preferences -> Team -> SVN, it crashes with the following message:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f47a102b784, pid=5510, tid=139948294772480
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_80-b15) (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.80-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libapr-1.so.0+0x25784]  apr_threadkey_private_get+0x4
```

I'm using Java 1.7, but tried with 1.8 as well.

My eclipse.ini looks like this:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.php.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni/
-Duser.name=mmaluga
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-javaagent:/opt/eclipse-mars/plugins/com.zeroturnaround.eclipse.optimizer.plugin_1.0.9/agent/eclipse-optimizer-agent.jar
-Xverify:none
-server
-XX:+UseParallelGC
```

You can have a look at the [error report](http://pastebin.com/CLLdrvi5). I use SVNKit for now, but it lack some features required by Sublipse (i.e. merging does not work)

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

I have found the answer. While preparing the question above I noticed the following information on Subclipse website:

> Subclipse 1.12.x update site has been created with support for Subversion 1.9.x.  As explained in the following discussion post for now this site still contains Subclipse 1.10.x but with support for Subversion 1.9.x added.  **Due to how the JavaHL library is loaded we cannot maintain support for both 1.8.x and 1.9.x using a single update site.**

I checked which version of SVN I have installed and which version of Subclipse. I had SVN 1.8 and Subclipse for 1.9. I removed Subclipse and installed version 1.10.x. That solved the problem.